# How can I plot weather data?

Tags: plotting, curated-data

```
temperatures1 = 
  WeatherData["London", "Temperature", {{2013, 8, 14}];

temperatures3 = 
  WeatherData["London", "Temperature", {{2013, 8, 15}]
ListPlot[{temperatures1,temperatures3}]
```

How can i do this for  for yesterday's `"MeanHumidity"` compared to today's mean temperature ?

Comment: thanks for editing it,can u tell me plz how can i do it?

Comment: I think you should use `MeanTemperature`. To find out all available properties, type `WeatherData["Properties"]`. Have a look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57583/how-can-i-write-a-function-whose-argument-is-a-date-and-whose-output-is-the-ave

Comment: Thank lot it help me lot

Answer (score 2):

```
{meanhumidity, meantemp} = 
   WeatherData["London", #, {{2007, 1, 1}, {2007, 12, 31}, "Day"}] & /@ { 
      "MeanHumidity", "MeanTemperature"}; 
plotdata = Transpose[{meanhumidity[[;; -2, 2]], meantemp[[2 ;;, 2]]}];
ListPlot[plotdata, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Mean Humidity [t-1]", "Mean Temp [t]"}]
```

[image]